# How to read this XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML file. There is only one row.
I need to read the file from its path and add the information to separate strings
(dateJoined, totals, partials, status and counter).

For the moment I read the XML file like this:

```
var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@pathXML);
```

I am very noob at C# but I need to solve this problem.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
    <METADATA>
            <FIELDS>
                <FIELD attrname="dateJoined" fieldtype="dateTime"/>
                <FIELD attrname="totals" fieldtype="r8"/>
                <FIELD attrname="partials" fieldtype="r8"/>
                <FIELD attrname="status" fieldtype="r8"/>
                <FIELD attrname="counter" fieldtype="r8"/>
            </FIELDS>
        <PARAMS/>
    </METADATA>
    
    <ROWDATA>
        <ROW dateJoined="20201027" totals="41314.91" partials="134.55" status="2" counter="126"/>
    </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

How can I get all the attributes of the row in separate variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this: get the `<ROWDATA>` node, then its first (and only) descendant, and from that node, extract the info from the attributes with this code:

```
var field = xml.Root.Descendants("ROWDATA").Descendants().FirstOrDefault();

if (field != null)
{
    string dateJoined = field.Attribute("dateJoined").Value;
    decimal total = decimal.Parse(field.Attribute("totals").Value);
    decimal partials = decimal.Parse(field.Attribute("partials").Value);

    int status = int.Parse(field.Attribute("status").Value);
    int counter = int.Parse(field.Attribute("counter").Value);
}
```

**UPDATE**: as @KlausGütter has noted in comments - if your .NET culture you're using uses something other than a dot (`.`) as its decimal separator, then this code won't properly convert the strings representing the `decimal` values.

To check what the decimal separator is, use this:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Number.CurrencyDecimalSeparator
```

To properly convert the XML data to `decimal` in such a case, use:

```
    decimal total = (decimal)field.Attribute("totals");
    decimal partials = (decimal)field.Attribute("partials");
```

Comment: @marc_s Is there a reason why you prefer `int.Parse(field.Attribute("status").Value)` instead of the more concise `(int)field.Attribute("status")` (see [XAttribute cast operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit?view=netcore-3.1))?

Comment: @KlausGütter: no, not really - guess I'm just more used to the `int.Parse()` approach in general

Comment: @marc_s In case of the decimal attributes, your implementation is incorrect if the current culture has a decimal separator other than '.'.

Comment: @KlausGütter: thanks for the heads-up - checked and verified with the `de-DE` culture and updated my response accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative that's a little more flexible, use XPath.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load( @yourxmlfilenamepathhere);
XmlElement field = (XmlElement)xml.SelectSingleNode( "//ROWDATA/ROW" );
```

The rest of the code is the same.

The benefit, is that it won't break on most XML structure changes, and the XPath approach is simpler, especially if your looking way down deep in nested XML.